# how to automatically publish the post on my app facebook page using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a blogging application in Ruby on Rails.

I want to publish all the blogs which are published on my rails application to my facebook page automatically from background jobs.

I explore the Facebook Graph Api Feed Api and do some hit and try but didn't get any success.

So could anyone please suggest that how I achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, definitely the gem you are looking for is [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)

It is a lightweight, flexible library for Facebook with support for OAuth authentication, the Graph and REST APIs, realtime updates. It also allows you to post on your page.

It also allows you to post pictures and videos on Facebook

[Here](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki) is a complete documentation for this gem